# Efficiently expanding a time window categorical in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Given boolean array with a `Timedelta` index, how can I make any samples within some `Timedelta` of an existing `True`, also `True`?

Another way of thinking about it might be: how can I "grow" the `True` regions of my boolean array by a given `Timedelta`.

My current implementation below works fine, but is quite slow.

```py
df["valid_region_extended"] = df.valid_region.copy()
extension_period = pd.Timedelta(seconds=0.01)
for index in df.valid_region.index:
    window_start = index - extension_period
    window_end = index + extension_period
    if df.valid_region[window_start:window_end].any():
        df.valid_region_extended[index] = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your index is evenly spaced, you could [**`shift()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) the boolean array both directions and [**`sum()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) them:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'valid': [False]*3+[True]+[False]*7+[True]*2+[False]*6+[True]}, index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-20'))

pad = 2 # derive from Timedelta
df = df.assign(**{f'valid{n}': df.valid.shift(n) for n in range(-pad, pad+1)})
df['final'] = df.sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

Original vs expanded:

```
            valid  final
2021-01-01  False  False
2021-01-02  False   True
2021-01-03  False   True
2021-01-04   True   True
2021-01-05  False   True
2021-01-06  False   True
2021-01-07  False  False
2021-01-08  False  False
2021-01-09  False  False
2021-01-10  False   True
2021-01-11  False   True
2021-01-12   True   True
2021-01-13   True   True
2021-01-14  False   True
2021-01-15  False   True
2021-01-16  False  False
2021-01-17  False  False
2021-01-18  False   True
2021-01-19  False   True
2021-01-20   True   True
```

Comment: Hmm. It's not evenly spaced, but interpolating, shifting and then decimating is likely to still be more efficient. I'll give that a try, thanks